# How to migrate Link Fields ('title' and 'url') involving local variables?

Tags: 7, entities, navigation, migrations

I have performed the following query:

```
$query = db_select('sage.USER', 'USER')
  ->fields('USER', array('USER_ID', 'OFFICE_ID', 'USER_PASSWORD'))
  ->range(0, 1);
$result = $query->execute();
...
$url = '/sage/office-' . $result->office_id;
$arguments = MigrateLinkFieldHandler::arguments(array('source_field' => 'office_id'));
$this->addFieldMapping('field_office_id', $url);
  ->arguments($arguments);
```

However, the above is not working. I would like to manipulate the 'office_id' field to be used as the 'title' and the variable $url to be used as the URL that was linked. I have followed what's on this [post](http://drupal.org/node/1004066)

Could someone please point out my mistakes?

EDIT: Updated question to reflect jdu's answer.

Comment: could anyone provide any insight into the correctness of my syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The `link.migrate.inc` file is not included in the Migrate Extras module, it's part of the [Link module](http://drupal.org/project/link).

The file doesn't exist in the stable version of Link, but it *does* exist in the [dev release](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/link-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz). I think you're going to have to install the dev version of Link if you want this to work.

If you install the dev version and still get the error it's most likely because the file is not being automatically included. If that's the case try adding this to the top of your code:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'link', 'link.migrate');
```

**EDIT**

As I mentioned in your [other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28271/how-to-obtain-contents-from-a-drupal-7-query) there's a slight error in your code, you should change this line:

```
$result = $query->execute();
```

to:

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
```

That will return an object representing the first result that was returned by the query.

Comment: Hi Clive thank you very much. I've found the file and put it in link.migrate.inc and it no longer complains about the file. I am now just getting partial, incomplete migrations of the link 'title' and 'url' fields.

Comment: I just answered your newer question, that might help a bit :)

Comment: Yes it does a lot! I don't know if it's proper, but should I give you the bounty for it? Even though you answered the one without it lol...

Comment: I really don't know to be honest, seems like these questions should be merged but I don't think that can be done when there's a bounty open on one of them. It might be worth asking a question on how best to proceed on the [meta site](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/), I'm sure one of the mods will weigh in :)

Comment: Questions are merged if the questions are exact duplicates; in this case, the other question is more generic than this one, and they cannot be merged. Also, the answer for this question ("The `link.migrate.inc` file is not included in the Migrate Extras module") is not the answer for the other question.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I imported nodes:

- Download link.migrate.inc from link 7.x dev version and add this file to your module
- Add file entry in your .info module (files[] = link.migrate.inc)
- Apply this patch [link-migrate_subfields.patch](http://drupal.org/node/1715378)
- Then you can use the following code:

  ```
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_portrait_affiliation_link', 'field_portrait_affiliation_link');
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_portrait_affiliation_link:title', 'field_portrait_affiliation_link:title');
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_portrait_affiliation_link:attributes', 'field_portrait_affiliation_link:attributes');
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_portrait_affiliation_link:language', 'language');
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Fill a new variable with the results of executing your query:

```
$result = $query->execute();

$url = 'office-' . $result->office_id;
```

Comment: jdu, still crashing, it says Class MigrateLinkFieldHandler could not be found. I thought this was included in Migrate Extras?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/migrate_extras

yep, says it's built in.  is there a file called "link.migrate.inc" ?

perhaps installation of the module failed somehow.  I'd upload the module to the directory again, check permissions and dependencies.

there's always the web servers "error_log" file too, just in case something is being generated in there that could be more helpful.

Comment: hmm thanks it really isn't in there...i'll keep digging..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked: /admin/content/migrate/configure

There check the Field handlers for the link field:

[x] link  MigrateLinkFieldHandler   link_field

Install the dev version of the Link module. Then this should work:

```
....
$arguments = array('title' => array('source_field' => 'office_id'));
$this->addFieldMapping('field_office_id', 'field_office_id_path')->arguments($arguments);
...

function prepareRow($row) {
    $row->field_office_id_path = '/sage/office-' . $row->office_id;
}
```

Comment: $arguments = array('title' => array('source_field' => 'office_id'));

should be

$arguments = array(array('source_field' => 'office_id'));