# How to obtain contents from a drupal 7 query?

Tags: 7

I am trying to perform the below simple query:

```
$query = db_select('sage.USER', 'USER')
  ->fields('USER', array('USER_ID', 'OFFICE_ID'));
$result = $query->execute();
```

I would like to then pull out the 'office_id' that is returned by the query, which I have been told can be done with the following:

```
$office = $result->office_id;
```

However, when I do 'print_r($office)' or 'echo $office', it would seem the $office string is empty. The database is not empty and contains the appropriate values.

Could someone please how I can pull out the contents of a drupal 7 query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute()` returns a resource you can iterate over in a `foreach` loop, e.g:

```
foreach ($result as $record) {
  $office_id = $record->office_id;
}
```

In your case you probably want to use the `fetchObject()` method to actually retrieve the first record returned from the query:

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
$office = $result->office_id;
```

Comment: I am trying to do this in a Migrate class. If I do $result->execute()->fetchObject() I will only ever get the first office_id and that will be used for all my records. If I do $result->execute() and loop over the records with foreach, then only the last office_id will be used for all the records...is there a way I can make it so the office_ids are used in sequential order?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with custom Migrate classes, but going off the code in your other question it seems like you need to add a condition to your db query. Is the code for your class very long? It might be worth posting it in a new question so people can offer advice, it gets a bit tricky to debug code in the comments and editing the answer with stuff not relevant to the original question might make this thread lose its focus